# AuthorizeAttribute adal signout MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, adal

I have created a custom Authorize attribute based on AAD groups in MVC. If I return false in the attribute the applications goes into an infinite loop on the login page. How do you signoff the user from an custom authorize attribute when using adal in an MVC application?

Comment: I think you are mixing concerns a bit there. An authorization attribute is supposed to check if the user is authorized to do an action, and either allow them through or return some kind of error that they are not allowed to do that. Why do you need to sign them out?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If the user is not member of a specific AAD group then I return false because I dont want to authorize the user. If your using ADAL/OWIN as authentication and return false from a custom authorize attribute then the applications starts an infinite loop towards you login page and your application.

Comment: Yeah, you usually don't want to cause a redirection to AAD on authorization failure (it'll start a game of tennis with your browser as the ball and your app and AAD as the rackets). Instead you should show an error page to the user.

Comment: Btw forget that it is always signing user out, just for testing purpose :D

Comment: Or even better:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user is authenticated but does not have the role(false returned in custom attribute) the authorize attribute will change the response to 401. It is only when the user is authenticated and have the role (true returned in custom attribute) that the authorize attribute won’t change the response.

If you are using FormsAuthentication or the OWIN Cookie Authentication Middleware and the user is already logged in , he will be redirected to the login page again, which is kind of weird if you thing about it. "I've already logged in, and now I'm back do the log in page just because I clicked some link, and no one told me why this just happened."

AuthorizeAttribute provides a protected virtual method named HandleUnauthorizedRequest that you can override, checking whether user is authenticated and show an erro page . For example :

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }
```

You could also  redirect an unauthorised user in your custom AuthorisationAttribute by overriding the HandleUnauthorizedRequest method:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new
                        { 
                            controller = "Error", 
                            action = "Unauthorised" 
                        })
                );
}
```

Please read [here](http://www.blinkingcaret.com/2016/01/20/authorization-redirect-loops-asp-net-mvc/) for more details .

Comment: Thats the way to go! Thats a far better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
I think I found a solution I am testing as we speak: 

protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        var allowedGroups = GetAllowedGroups();

        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
        string callbackUrl = urlHelper.Action("SignOutCallback", "Account", routeValues: null, protocol: httpContext.Request.Url.Scheme);

        httpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        return authorized;
    }
```